# Cannot find node module 'node:fs' when using js and trying to deploy to my personal server that runs linux

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

> ```
> Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
>    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/doge/atlas/db-bot/Index.js:1:12)
>    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> ```

My package.JSON file:

```json
{
  "name": "atlas-db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[REDACTED]",
  "main": "Index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "none"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/[REDACTED]/db-bot.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "bot"
  ],
  "author": "[REDACTED]",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/[REDACTED]/db-bot/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/[REDACTED]/db-bot#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.13.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.32.1"
  }
}
```

I've ran `npm i`

I've tried everything.
It works on Windows but not Linux, I have no clue why.

Just saying that this happens in every file that requires "node:x"

Its really odd.

My index:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: are you using Typescript ?

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad Nope

Comment: `const fs = require('node:fs');` thats the error, it should be   ```const fs = require('fs');```

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: @Seti `const fs = require('node:fs');` is supported in v18, and is the primary documentation you land on if you search for 'node fs' in google, so per usual: it depends.

Comment: @EddieDean if its not working, then i can presume the version he is using does not support it - so proper conclusion would be to remove 'node:' from require. Thats why i wrote to him to remove that part

Answer (score 21):

I believe you're reading nodejs v18 docs, while not having nodejs v18 installed on your system. Since `node:fs` is introduced in v18, `fs` is the package for versions previous than that. Either upgrade nodejs to v18 or else simply rename `node:fs` to `fs`.

Comment: the prefixing of 'node:' for require of internal modules has apparently been back ported to version 16 and 14.

Comment: Oh, might have been then! I believe it was done to improve compatibility across different runtimes like Deno & Bun, not to mention it makes it easier to understand that whether the package is third party or native.

Answer (score 0):

use NVM to switch to a newer version of Node/NPM